# Seeking software to replace ArcGIS completely

Tags: software-recommendations, desktop-gis

I'm a longtime ArcGIS user so very familiar with the Esri environment but ArcGIS Pro has myriad issues. I'm not really sure what else is out there that can compete, but I'm spending way too much time redoing processes, finding workarounds for bugs, or just waiting for a process to run - which is very slow more often than not. I've been doing some tasks/processing in QGIS for several years but I don't see how it could ever totally replace ArcGIS.

My machine exceeds the specs, etc.